# Running python file using spawn in node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process, spawn

I am trying to run python file on a post request from client(react js). Everything was working fine on the other windows 10 system. But when I tried to use it on another computer, now it is not working. On terminal, it is showing no error.

This is my server.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const { request } = require("http");
const { response } = require("express");
const { stderr } = require("process");


function denoiseVideoByRaw(req, res) {
  
  var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

  // raw audio
  var process = spawn("python", ["denoise_video.py"], {shell: true});

  process.stdout.on("data", function async(data) {
    // res.send(data.toString());
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
}
app.post("/denoise-video-by-raw", denoiseVideoByRaw);


app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("server is running on localhost:8000");
});
```

Comment: Please add `error` listener right after the `data` listener, to show us what is the error. `process.stdout.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Failed', err);
});`

Comment: You are saying you can run `denoise_video.py` from the terminal with no error, but not when posted through the nodejs server? Or just that nothing is being logged?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei no error is shown on the console after adding this line.

Comment: @chrisbyte yes, when I am running the python file from terminal, it is executing but not from the node js server. And the exact same code was working on my other computer, but when I tried to run it on someone else's pc, now it is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Node.js [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options), you need to also capture `stderr`.

Please apply these changes:

```js
var result = '';
process.stdout.on('data', function (data) { // The callback function no need to be as async
    result += data.toString(); // each data is a chunk
});
```

**stderr**:

```js
process.stderr.on('data', function (data){
    result += data.toString();
});
```

**final result**:

```js
process.stdout.on('end',function (data){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Um, you don't _need_ to capture stderr.

Comment: In case of any output error, it should be! In Node.js examples, we can see they put `stderr` alongside `stdout`

Comment: Or you can set the spawn option `stdio` to `'inherit'` so no output is redirected at all.

Comment: You're right, Although I personally prefer to always define `stderr` as it gives us more control. If I want to give an example, it is like a server always returns 200 and if there is an error, it returns 200 again and puts the error code in the response body.

Comment: However, regards to OP's code, `stdio` didn't set to `inherit`, so it needs to capture `stderr`

Comment: TBH In OP's case `stdio` should be set to `['ignore', 'pipe', 'inherit']` so stderr is printed out automagically (for ease of debugging) and `stdin` isn't used at all.

Comment: Feel free to edit the post, and add your suggestion.